# How can I filter generic list by reflection in c#

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a generic list. I have to filter the list based on the value of the property of list item. Item type is not known until runtime.

I have to find the item type by reflection and then need to filter.

Please help me by any idea or example

Thanks.

Comment: Could you add a code example of what you're trying to do/what you have tried?

Comment: You can use `.OfType` on your list to filter by type: `list.OfType<filterType>()` - but it's unlikely that covers your "by reflection" requirement.

Comment: "Item type is not known until runtime" - what mechanism are you using to *specify* the item type at runtime?  How do you know that the type (at runtime) has the property you want?  What's your base type defined against the 'generic list' or is it just `var list = new [];` and you've not used the correct terms.  Including your code so-far would help answer these questions.

Comment: Thanks  @JoachimIsaksson ,
Let me explain what I am trying to do:
I have some services that returns a generic list (actually IEnumerable). All the services pass through a filter method where I need to filter the list based on the user’s  access level. From this method I have to filter the list.
I can get the type by reflection but the problem is I cannot cast the IEnumerable to list its type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Hope this help

pass any list, and specify a property name, and a filter method

```
     private IList FilterList(IList list, string propName, Predicate<object> filterMethod) {
        var result = new List<object>();
        foreach (var item in list) {
            var value = item.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(item);
            if (filterMethod(value)) {
                result.Add(item);
            }
        }
        return result;

    }
```

Example :

```
var result = FilterList(list, "Age", age => (int)age >= 18);
```

you can develop it and make it fully dynamic

Comment: Thanks @yousif.aljamri,
Your solution is working if I know the property type in advance.  From your example if I don’t cast Age to int it is not working.
I don’t know the property type in advance. How can I filter then?

Comment: @BulbulAhmed how detailed is your filter ? , and from where it comes?, if it's simple text filter, it's easier

Answer (score 1):

If the list is generic you *should* know at least a base type at compile time.

If the base type contains the property - just use it.

If only some of the subtypes(ideally one) contain the property you're interested in you can do a [cast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.100).aspx) on the list and then use your property.

```
list.Cast<Derived>().Select(i => i.Property == "val");
```

If that is not ok(say the type of the list has many derived types that contain the property and others that do not), you can use dynamic with a try/catch block.

```
list.Select(i => {
                   try
                   {
                       dynamic item = i;
                       return item.Prop == "value";
                   }
                   catch(RuntimeBinderException)   //this type doesn't contain the property
                   {
                       return false;
                   }
                });
```

Comment: Thanks @Bond,
I can only know the derived type by reflection. How can I cast it to a list of it’s type?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It can determine whether a List is a list of some specified type. Based on that you should be able to filter for any specific type.

```
public class TypeA
{ }
public class TypeB
{ }

public class GenericFilter
{
    public bool IsOfType<T>(IEnumerable<dynamic> objectToInspect)
    {
        var genericType = objectToInspect.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[0];
        return genericType == typeof(T);
    }
}


[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void IdentifiesExpectedType()
    {
        var classToInspect = new List<TypeA>();
        var filter = new GenericFilter();
        Assert.IsTrue(filter.IsOfType<TypeA>(classToInspect));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void RejectsNonMatchingType()
    {
        var classToInspect = new List<TypeA>();
        var filter = new GenericFilter();
        Assert.IsFalse(filter.IsOfType<TypeB>(classToInspect));
    }
}
```

---

This works just as well:

```
public bool IsOfType<T>(IEnumerable<dynamic> listToFilter)
{
    return (listToFilter as IEnumerable<T>) != null;
}
```

---

This will take a list of lists and group them into a `Dictionary<Type, List<List<dynamic>>` where all of the lists for each key are of that type. That way you can select lists of type T just by retrieving them from the dictionary.

```
    public Dictionary<Type, List<List<dynamic>>> GroupListsByType(List<List<dynamic>> lists)
    {
        var types = lists.Select(list => list.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[0]).Distinct().ToList();
        var grouped = new Dictionary<Type, List<List<dynamic>>>();
        types.ForEach(type =>
        {
            grouped.Add(type, new List<List<dynamic>>());
            grouped[type].AddRange(lists.Where(list=>list.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[0] == type));
        });
        return grouped;
    }
```

(I'm not questioning the "why." I don't know if I would recommend this, but it's interesting to write.)